# How can I slurp file names from a RoboCopy log?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm stuck matching file names from a Robocopy log file. When formulating the regex pattern in Visual Studio text editor, what works there does not work in .NET code. I think this is because StreamReader.Readline() is removing \r (0x0D) or changing the end of the line which breaks the pattern I wrote. I've been rat-holing on this and need to reach out for help.  There are two cases to match a file name. In the first case: #1 there is a \r (0x0D) after the file name and other case: #2 there is a \t after the file name.

In Visual Studio 2015, the following pattern was working for all file names in the example, but in .NET there is no match on .DS_Store:

```
(?<=New File.+)(?<=\d\t)(.*?\t|.*?\r)
```

log file:

```
      New Dir          7    \\vboxsvr\win8devdocs\pictures\
        New File            8196    .DS_Store
  0%  
100%  
        New File            6607    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt   17:58 -> 17:58
  0%  
100%  
        New File         1198408    IMG_20131124_125621_954.jpg 17:58 -> 17:58
  0%  
 21%  
 43%  
 65%  
 87%  
100%  
        New File         1132046    IMG_20131212_104250_300.jpg 17:58 -> 17:58
```

Method that reads the Robocopy file and saves the file name and directory of the copied files (but doesn't handle copy failures yet):

```
private void LogCopiedFiles(string absRoboLogPath, string absFileCopyListLog) {
    try {
        UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        using(FileStream write = File.OpenWrite(absFileCopyListLog)) 
        using(StreamReader read = File.OpenText(absRoboLogPath)) {
            string currentDir = string.Empty;
            while(!read.EndOfStream) {
                string line     = read.ReadLine();
                Match newDir    = findDirNamesInLog.Match(line);
                Match newFile   = findFileNamesInLog.Match(line);

                if(newDir.Success) {
                    currentDir = newDir.Value;
                }
                else if(newFile.Success) {
                    byte[] byteLine = encoder.GetBytes(string.Concat(currentDir, newFile.Value, Environment.NewLine));
                    write.Write(byteLine, 0, byteLine.Length);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

What pattern could I use that would slurp up just the file name from the log in .NET?

Comment: Just an fyi, this `(?<=New File.+)(?<=\d\t)` is identical to `(?<=New File.*\d\t)`. Does not address the question though.

Comment: Is slurp a technical term here?

Comment: Not so much. Its Perl speak that means get. I saw it in a code comment years ago and it stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Note your original regex requires a tab. That's why it doesn't work because there is no tab in this string `8196 .DS_Store`

**Edit** Use this instead `New File.*?\d+(?!\d)[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)`

Matches

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 69 , len 37 ) 
New File            8196    .DS_Store  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 97 , len 9 ) 
.DS_Store  

-----------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 132 , len 273 ) 
New File            6607    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 160 , len 245 ) 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt  

-----------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 448 , len 55 ) 
New File         1198408    IMG_20131124_125621_954.jpg  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 476 , len 27 ) 
IMG_20131124_125621_954.jpg  

-----------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 576 , len 55 ) 
New File         1132046    IMG_20131212_104250_300.jpg  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 604 , len 27 ) 
IMG_20131212_104250_300.jpg
```

---

***Example Usage C#***

```
string [] LogLines = {
   @"      New Dir          7    \\vboxsvr\win8devdocs\pictures\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ",
   @"        New File            8196    .DS_Store                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ",
   @"  0%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @"100%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @"        New File            6607    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt   17:58 -> 17:58   ",
   @"  0%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @"100%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @"        New File         1198408    IMG_20131124_125621_954.jpg 17:58 -> 17:58                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ",
   @"  0%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @" 21%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @" 43%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @" 65%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @" 87%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @"100%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ",
   @"        New File         1132046    IMG_20131212_104250_300.jpg 17:58 -> 17:58                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "
};

Regex RxDir = new Regex(@"New Dir.*?\d+(?!\d)[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)");
Regex RxFile = new Regex(@"New File.*?\d+(?!\d)[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)");

Match matchDir;
Match matchFile;

for (int i = 0; i < LogLines.Count(); i++)
{
    string aline = LogLines[i];

    matchDir = RxDir.Match( aline );
    if ( matchDir.Success )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Directory = {0}", matchDir.Groups[1].Value );
    }
    else
    {
        matchFile = RxFile.Match( aline );
        if ( matchFile.Success )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "     File = {0}", matchFile.Groups[1].Value ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Directory = \\vboxsvr\win8devdocs\pictures\
     File = .DS_Store
     File = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt
     File = IMG_20131124_125621_954.jpg
     File = IMG_20131212_104250_300.jpg
```

Comment: That didn't match any. The pattern needs to match the file name when there is a carriage return after it or when there is a tab after it. The regular-expressions site mentions if then else condition, but I'm not sure how to use that or if it would apply.

Comment: No, it works. Copy from the new **edit** string. Somehow the old string got some invisible Unicode whitespace in it (00200C 00200B).

Comment: The problem was resolved by adding a carrage return to the line before running the regex and using the origninal pattern I had. But I tried your suggestion to mark the answer. After typing in the pattern (and double checking it) 
The result was: New File      380608 accesschk.exe. Expected: acesschk.exe

Comment: @5HPC6Z06 - Not sure what you mean. The original pattern is useless and never worked. You're going through gyrations with look around constructs just to match only the file or directory name. This is  _never_ the way to do this. The file or directory name is in **capture group 1**. _I posted a C# usage example_ to give you an idea how to access the group. Both _directory_ and _file name_ are done the same way.

Comment: Quite the contrary, sln. I didn't ask for what you delivered, thus it was your suggestions that are useless and never worked.

Comment: I think that tabs are turned into spaces in the SO editor. So if there is a tab `IMG_20131124_125621_954.jpg` <here> `17:58 -> 17:58` then your regex probably works, but you're relying on tabs and/or CR for delimiters.  Good luck to you!